# Why does my uploaded Youtube video go to Private (policy violation) when using API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube via a Python script.  I had this working on my primary account but decided to set it up on a dedicated google account.  Now every time I upload a video it goes to private due to policy violation through uploading via an unauthorised third party.

I have set up OAuth authentication and have my client_secrets.json file.

I am using the code here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

I have requested an OAuth content page review but i dont know if that's required.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you completed the step  - Register your application with Google? https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application link for the doc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  Yes I have done that but it is asking me for a homepage and privacy policy.  I don't have either of those - it's just a python script that's sitting on my raspberry pi!

Comment: You can use online privacy policy generators. just google them... i think that will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I think it does.  I've submitted everything I think I need to so I'll wait to see what Google come back with.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any update on if YouTube verified your app? I too am running something off a raspberry pi.